# Почему возникает java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java

При использовании данного кода:

```
package javaapplication;

import com.github.sardine.DavResource;
import com.github.sardine.Sardine;
import com.github.sardine.SardineFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class JavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Sardine sardine = SardineFactory.begin("login", "password");
        List<DavResource> resources;
        resources = sardine.list("http://yourdavserver.com/adirectory/");
        for (DavResource res : resources)
        {
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }

}
```

Возникает ошибка `NoClassDefFoundError`:

> run: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/HttpEntity    at
>   com.github.sardine.SardineFactory.begin(SardineFactory.java:44)   at
>   com.github.sardine.SardineFactory.begin(SardineFactory.java:34)   at
>   javaapplication.JavaApplication.main(JavaApplication.java:25) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 3 more
>   C:\Users\Levchenko\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему возникает ошибка. Возможно, я подключил не все библиотеки которые нужны.

Добавил библиотеки. В структуре проекта теперь 3 библиотеки: sardine, httpclient, http core. Вот что получилось:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.(AbstractVerifier.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier.(AllowAllHostnameVerifier.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier.(AllowAllHostnameVerifier.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:146)
>     at
>   com.github.sardine.impl.SardineImpl.createDefaultSecureSocketFactory(SardineImpl.java:1116)
>     at
>   com.github.sardine.impl.SardineImpl.createDefaultSchemeRegistry(SardineImpl.java:1099)
>     at
>   com.github.sardine.impl.SardineImpl.configure(SardineImpl.java:1064)
>     at com.github.sardine.impl.SardineImpl.(SardineImpl.java:203)
>     at com.github.sardine.SardineFactory.begin(SardineFactory.java:44)
>     at com.github.sardine.SardineFactory.begin(SardineFactory.java:34)
>     at javaapplication.JavaApplication.main(JavaApplication.java:25)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 11 more
>   C:\Users\Levchenko\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1

Comment: как вы компилируете это файл и как запускаете?

Comment: Работаю в NetBeans.

Comment: тогда вам необходимо добавить в зависимости библиотеку Apache Http Client. как это сделать написано [тут- Добавление зависимости](https://blogs.oracle.com/roumen/entry/netbeans_quick_tip_16_using)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Или в структуре проекта добавить библиотеку в папочку библиотеки.

Comment: лучше вариантом будет начать использовать систему сборки.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ошибка [NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) возникает когда класс от которого зависит ваше приложение недоступен при исполнении кода.

Описание ошибки в документации:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
> load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
> as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
> definition of the class could be found.
> The searched-for class
> definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled,
> but the definition can no longer be found.
>
> *Вольный перевод:*
> Выбрасывается когда виртуальная машина Java или загрузчик классов пытается загрузить определение класса (при стандартном вызове метода либо при создании экземпляра класса с конструктора) и при этом определение класса не удалось обнаружить.
> Искомое определение класса существовало при компиляции текущего класса, но при исполнении не может быть найдено

Скорее всего ошибка вызвана тем, что одна из библиотек, требуемых для работы вашего приложения не добавлена в classpath.

Для исправления ошибки нужно:

- посмотреть на имя отсутствующего класса в сообщении об ошибке;
- проверить при обращении к какому классу возникает ошибка;
- найти библиотеку (зависимость, если используется система сборки Maven, Gradle), в которой находится класс;
- проверить что библиотека доступна при исполении кода (JAR-файл библиотеки находится в classpath).

Похожий вопрос в английской версии Stackoverflow:

- [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

**Ваш пример**

В данном случае имя класса org/apache/http/HttpEntity. Он находится в библиотеке Apache HttpComponents Core. Скачать ее можно в репозитории Maven (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.3).

Sardine [зависит](https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine/blob/master/pom.xml) от библиотеки [Apache HttpComponents Client версии 4.5.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1), которая в свою очередь зависит от Apache HttpComponents Core версии 4.4.3.
Скорее всего Вам понадобится подключить обе эти библиотеки как минимум.

Добавьте библиотеки и попробуйте запустить заново.

Comment: Сейчас попробую всё сделать. Мне необходимо просто добавить библиотеки в библиотеки проекта, да? Apache HttpComponents Client версии 4.5.1 и Apache HttpComponents Core версии 4.4.3? Спасибо за такой развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: @ELe это должно помочь с текущей ошибкой. Если используется не последняя версия Sardine (5.7 или 5.8), то зависимости могут быть другими. Также, возможно, отсутствуют другие библиотеки.

Comment: Посмотрите вопрос, я отредактировал, добавил 2 библиотеки в проект как вы и сказали. Мне нужно ещё делать импорт классов в коде программы?

Comment: @ELe вот для того я и написал развернутый ответ, чтобы Вы могли сами разобраться с ошибкой :) На странице [httpclient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1) есть раздел compile-time dependencies. Добавьте все три зависимости там: 1) httpcore уже должен быть; 2) [commons-codec 1.9](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9); 3) [commons-logging 1.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2)

Comment: Поиском искал compile-time но не нашёл на той странице, сейчас попробую добавить.

Comment: @ELe Да, просто "Compile dependencies", прошу прощения)

Comment: Урааа, run:/;/Apps/;/Files/;СБОРКА УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНА. Спасибо Вам за помощь :) Получается я подключил все зависимости sardine? Я на этой странице https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine/blob/master/pom.xml не понимаю, даже эти компоненты не увидил, только org.apache.httpcomponents.

Comment: @ELe Поздравляю! POM.xml —это файл конфигурации [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). Maven — это система сборки, которая позволяет удобно управлять зависимостями. Если бы Вы использовали ее, Вам не пришлось бы отыскивать зависимости вручную, они бы определились автоматически. Компоненты Вы не видите т.к. это зависимости зависимостей (sardine зависит от httpclient, httpclient — от httpcore, commons-logging и commons-codec).

Comment: Сейчас попробую установить Maven, спасибо)

Comment: Я посмотрел в подключаемых модулях Netbeans и оказывается что у меня установлен Maven. Получается при создании проекта выбирать Maven -> Приложение, потом будет достаточно добавить только Sardine и Maven загрузит необходимые зависимости?

Comment: @ELe да, полный пакет Netbeans включает Maven. Да, можно просто создать приложение, но лучше предварительно пройтись по документации на сайте Maven