# Не работает нейросеть

Tags: java

```
NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork = new Perceptron(2, 1);

    DataSet trainingSet =
            new DataSet(2, 1);
    trainingSet. addRow (new DataSetRow(new double[]{0, 0},
            new double[]{0}));
    trainingSet. addRow (new DataSetRow (new double[]{0, 1},
            new double[]{1}));
    trainingSet. addRow (new DataSetRow (new double[]{1, 0},
            new double[]{1}));
    trainingSet. addRow (new DataSetRow (new double[]{1, 1},
            new double[]{1}));
    neuralNetwork.learn(trainingSet);
    neuralNetwork.save("on.nnet")
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не хватает библиотеки slf4j

Comment: Существует [35 вопросов с NoClassDefFoundError](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=NoClassDefFoundError), может кто-нибудь подберёт/создаст эталонный вопрос/ответ? Закрывать как оффтоп вряд ли стоит... Хм, вроде нашёл норм

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633793/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: maven зависимости покажите

Comment: Помимо slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar вам ещё нужен slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar