# Исключение NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

Мучаюсь с этой проблемой не один день и надеюсь на подсказку кто с этим сталкивался. Приложение ЛЮБОЕ(maven, java) с ЛЮБЫМИ jar выбрасывает исключение при запуске с командной строки. В Eclipse запускается без проблем. Попробовал запускать на своем старом ноуте - работает. Полагаю проблема в настройках компьютера(classpath?) поэтому не вижу смысла прилагать какой-либо код или jar файлы.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
        at crawler4j.basic.BasicCrawlController.<clinit>(BasicCrawlController.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633793/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633793/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger

Означает. что недоступна в вашем `CLASSPATH` библиотека `log4jXXX.jar` - 
библиотека [логгера LOG4J](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)

Почитайте как включить в CLASSPATH тот или иной архив JAR - [например здесь](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html)

или посмотрите строку запуска в Eclipse - он то запускает правильно, поэтому ничего не падает

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете maven для сборки приложения, я бы посоветовал почистить локальный maven репозиторий. В эклипсе есть свой встроенный maven, и скорее всего он у вас и используется для сборки.

Answer (score 1):

Собрал приложение в Maven и добавил classpath:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Вроде нормально теперь все.