# NoDefClassFoundError при запуски TestNg тестов на Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, java, testng

Регулярно получаю NoDefClassFoundError, при запуске тестов на дженкинсе. Раньше это были классы из других модулей, но сейчас начали падать и классы из одного модуля с тестами.

Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633793/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: @МихаилРебров спасибо за попытку, но совсем не в ту степь, я знаю из-за чего обычно возникает эта ошибка, здесь же проблема в том, что классы каждый раз новые и иногда падают классы с одного и того же пакета

Comment: без конфигурации, проекта, pom.xml/build.gradle больше ничего сказать и нельзя...

Comment: попробуйте открыть консоль, зайти в ворксепйс Jenkins и там выполнить те же команды, которые должен выполнить Jenkins...

Comment: Как запускаете? Пользуетесь ли каким-либо сборщиком?