# Message Send to Email

Tags: java, email, sendmail

Ребята хочу отправить песьмо на имейл но у меня на 28 строке исключение 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MessageRemovedIOException
    at SendToMail.main(SendToMail.java:28):
Что неправильно ?

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SendToMail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "******";
        final String password = "*******";

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //TLS

        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("*******"));
            message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("********")
            );
            message.setSubject("Testing Gmail TLS");
            message.setText("Hello,"
                    + "\n\n !");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633793/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: Скорее всего вы подтянули не все библиотеки. Покажите, как и чем вы собирали проект.