# Ошибка при отправке письма javaxmail

Tags: java, email

Вот мой код

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;



public class EmailLesson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(EmailLesson.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mail.properties"));

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("icpcsenondaryemail@gmail.com")); //почта отправителя
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("icpcsenondaryemail@gmail.com")); //Почта получателя
        message.setSubject("New user");
        message.setText("edit1");

        Transport tr = mailSession.getTransport();
        tr.connect(null, "mypassw0rd");
        tr.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        tr.close();
    }
    }
```

Вот ошибка которую я получаю

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler
    at EmailLesson.main(EmailLesson.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataHandler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
```

На сколько я понимаю что то не так в 18 строчке

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
```

Прошу помочь решить проблему с отправкой письма на email
Если что у меня javaxmail включён в Project Structure

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633793/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: Не хватает библиотеки. Можете добавить зависимость: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/javax.activation/1.2.0 Или скачать по ссылке JAR, как удобнее