# at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method), at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) - эти ошибки я получаю при запуске моего приложения

Tags: java, android, плагин

у меня есть Unity приложение, которое использует java плагин, и когда я его запускаю то первым делом оно вылетает, а дальше мне в AndroidStudio в logcat выдает следующие ошибки:

```
2021-04-26 16:46:39.893 23476-23537/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
Process: com.DefaultCompany.pluginsTest, PID: 23476
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.loadcamerajavacode.LoadCamera
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.loadcamerajavacode.LoadCamera
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) 
2021-04-26 16:46:39.997 1730-2755/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '4cb3c06 
com.DefaultCompany.pluginsTest/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

тут указана какая-то ошибка на 454 строке, вот код с соответствующей строкой:

```
@CallerSensitive
public static Class<?> forName(String name, boolean initialize,
                               ClassLoader loader)
    throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
    if (loader == null) {
        loader = BootClassLoader.getInstance();
    }
    Class<?> result;
    try {
 //  вот та самая 454 строка: result = classForName(name, initialize, loader);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Throwable cause = e.getCause();
        if (cause instanceof LinkageError) {
            throw (LinkageError) cause;
        }
        throw e;
    }
    return result;
}
```

в интернете на эту тему чего-то внятного не нашел, на одном сайте написано что проблема в BaseActivity.java, но я все же не пойму в чем конкретно, поэтому задаю вопрос здесь. Кто нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой? из-за чего она происходит? спасибо заранее.

Comment: Ошибки, так же как и код, лучше выкладывать текстом, а не скринами. Так и отвечающим проще и поиск лучше работает (иногда можно даже увидеть такой же вопрос с готовыми ответами в колонке "похожие"). Лог, похоже, не полный и причина не понятна. Показывайте код, относящийся к проблеме - может там чего увидим. И у вас точно есть класс, на который указывает ошибка - может вы имя не верно указали в вызове?

Comment: спасибо за Ваш комментарий! поправил!

Comment: @Hope1_ Проблема не в 454 строке. Тебе должна быть интересна вот эта строка: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.loadcamerajavacode.LoadCamera` [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59087196/crash-using-camerax-library-android-java-lang-classnotfoundexception) аналогичный вопрос.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за Ваш комментарий! переходил по ссылке что Вы скинули, там предлагается добавить некоторый код в build.gradle, я все сделал как там показано, ошибка никуда не исчезла. Вы также упомянули что мне должна быть интересна вот эта строка:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.loadcamerajavacode.LoadCamera 
поэтому вот возможный ответ на мой вопрос, сейчас буду разбираться: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633793/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror