# Ошибка java.lang.NoSuchMethodError при использовании JUnit5, поставленным через spring boot starter test

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, eclipse, junit

У меня есть тест написанный на JUnit5 и Mockito.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CompanyTest {
    private static final Long COMPANY_ID = 1L;
    @Mock
    private  CrudRepository<Long,Company> companyRep;
    @Mock
    private  UserService userService;
    @Mock
    private  ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;
    @InjectMocks
    private CompanyService companyService;
    @Test
    void tests() {
        doReturn(Optional.of(new Company(COMPANY_ID))).when(companyRep).findById(COMPANY_ID);
        var actualResult = companyService.findById(COMPANY_ID);
        assertThat(actualResult).isPresent();
        var expactedResult = new CompanyReadDto(COMPANY_ID);
        actualResult.ifPresent(actual -> assertEquals(expactedResult,actual));
        
    }
}
```

При запуске теста, я получаю ошибку java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Set org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.getAncestors()'
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.getTestClassNames(StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.java:50)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.executionFinished(StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.java:39)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.executionFinished(DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.java:46)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.reportEngineFailure(OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:203)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:94)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Для добавления зависимостей для тестов, я использую spring-boot-starter-test.
Вот мой pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>dllk</groupId>
    <artifactId>start-spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>${java.version}</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>20</source>
                    <target>20</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633793/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)