# NoClassDefFoundError при использовании библиотеки Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Для считывания json-файла в коллекцию написан класс

```
    public class StartingFileJsonReader {
    public static <T, C extends Collection<T>> void readAndUpdate(String fileName, C collection) {
        try (FileReader fis = new FileReader(fileName);
             BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(fis)){
            String line;
            StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
                fileContent.append(line);
            }

            convert(fileContent.toString(), collection);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static <T, C extends Collection<T>> void convert(String json, C collection) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        T data = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<T>() {});
        collection.add(data);
    }


}
```

при компиляции вылетает следующее:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.<clinit>(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:37)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:400)
    at utilites.StartingFileJsonReader.convert(StartingFileJsonReader.java:35)
    at utilites.StartingFileJsonReader.readAndUpdate(StartingFileJsonReader.java:27)
    at Main.App.main(App.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633793/)

Comment: Такая ошибка указывает, что соответствующий класс не найден в classpath.  Покажите, как вы собираете и запускаете свой проект, также можно указать зависимости из `pom.xml` (или `build.gradle`),  смотря какой инструмент для сборки используется.

Comment: Я просто запускаю проект в Idea, библиотеки там подключены через jar-файлы,указанные в структуре проекта

Comment: Тупо не хватает джара в classpath, скорее всего `jackson-annotations-x.y.z.jar`

Comment: При запуске проекта в консоли указываются jar-файлы в classpath, посмотрите, есть ли там `jackson-annotations-2.xx.yy.jar`.

Comment: Допустим,я решил начать пользоваться Maven, я его скачал и поставил, что дальше?

Comment: </dependency>
        <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.4</version>
                </dependency>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
    </dependency>
Ч 2 ->>

Comment: </dependencies>
у меня получился такой pom.xml лежащий в src, ничего не изменилось,ошибка все еще вылетает
(на всякий случай закнул картинкой,мб более читаемо будет

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за попытки помочь, с Мавеном к сожалению так и не разобрался до конца,но буду пытаться.

Проблелема была в том что у меня стояли сначала jackson.core , а потом core и datablind, сейчас дорбавил annotations и все заработало. Лично мне было совсем не очевидно, что для базовой функции библиотеки нужно скачать ее полностью, когда она разбита по трем разным джарникам.